# Map view appears white

Tags: android, google-maps

Until recently map view was working ok but now appears white even though i get the address from the location out of it as you can see in the picture

[image]

What can it be the problem im out of guesses

the code is this

@Override
    public Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

```
    String url = String.format(
        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%f,%f&zoom=16&size=%dx300&sensor=false&key=%s",
        lat,
        lon,
        imageWidth,
        context.getResources().getString(R.string.mapApiKey2)
    );

    Log.d("MAP REQUEST ", "" + url);
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    InputStream in;
    try {
        in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Also my MapView works OK, so the problem is with this static map.

If i take the url generated in this code and paste it on the browser i get

`The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console`

but i dont understand because I have already activated it there

Comment: Any message in the error log?

Comment: no no errors regarding the map

Comment: Make sure you're using correct API key

Comment: My thoughts exactly, @AleksG but if there are no errors it can't be the API key.

Comment: @user3249477 Do review the log again carefully.  If it's an API key issue, then there will only be one line with `W/` message.

Comment: no the APIKEY is correct

Comment: If you are not having a error in your log, please post your code to help you to solve your problem.

Comment: in a minute just to be clear im using static map

Comment: Do you try convert a mapview to image?

Comment: look at the code it is already an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well It was just that I didn't activate the correct API, it seems like google now has different API's for different purposes.

I had activated only `Google Maps Android API v2` and everything was alright but now i had to activate also `Static Maps API`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few possibilities:

1. You changed the keystore to make the application (debug vs production), you need a different Google Maps API key for each keystore.
2. Are you able to access internet? In my case, I was using a VPN to access my app's webservice endpoints, but the VPN blocked internet access, causing my maps to become like this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My whole app is based on internet so yes i can access internet. Im still in debugging so i didnt change keystore but to be sure i just generated a new key and it is still the same

Comment: A down vote, really? I get this is not a final and comprehensive answer, but I dont have enough reputation to add comments, how else am I supposed to suggest things then?

Comment: its not me, im a low rep user too :/

Comment: Looks like I offended the high and mighty bureaucracy of StackOverflow...go on down voting, and you will continue to get half baked answers that should be comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Common mistake #1. **Please do not leave empty catch statements!** This can, and eventually will lead to hidden errors.

At least print the stackstrace in each of them:

```
e.printStackTrace():
```

Comment: good observation but I still dont get errors regarding the map

Comment: @Elgert Your update states that API key is not accepted. Try creating a new one. Perhaps your package name changed, since first creating the key?

Comment: I created a new one yesterday and double checked the SHA1 key and package name and they were correct :/